# Chrome DevTools First Paint in Performance TimeLine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There are a lot of Event in Chrome DevTolls Performance Event Log, I want to know which one represents for a real paint(paint to screen).

There is a Paint Event, but I don't know whether it is a real paint. In my opinion, Composite Layers represents for a real paint, but when First Paint Event fired, there may not be Composite Layers.

My questions:

1. Which one means real paint in Event Log, Paint or Composite Layers?
2. Does the first Paint event mean FP(First Paint)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Paint is just record of display list (draw rect, circles, color~)
   Composite layer is actually renderer main thread commits layers to compositor thread to composite layers later.

   real paint : paint -> raster -> gpu  and this is displayed next vsync.
2. Yes, it same as first pixel.